# wp_query 's' parameter does not work with custom post type

Tags: posts, wp-query, search, customization

I have a custom post type 'property'. I am trying to make a search for it, but it does not work with wp_query parameter 's'.

```
$wp_query = Wp_Query(['post_type' => 'property', 's' => 'test']);
```

It works fine with other Wp_query parameters, like this:

```
$wp_query = Wp_Query([
    'post_type' => 'property',
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'property_usage_type',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_GET['sb-usage-type'],
    ]
]);
```

It also works with other parameters except for 's'. But 's' is working with 'post' post type.
I also tried to echo out sql query - `$wp_query->request` but it is echos out anything unless I remove 's'.

Comment: 's' is just searching for the title & content but not for custom fields inside the custom post type. Are you searching for content in the custom post-type or are you searching for content of a custom field?

Comment: yes know that 's' is for title and content and I need to search title and content of custom post type. that custom field i inserted to show that wp query is working with other parameters  except for 's'

Comment: Can you update your question and show the form you are using?

Comment: Here is what I use for custom post types searches:
```$argsXXX = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'custom_type' 
);
```

And then 
```$loopXXX = new WP_Query( $argsXXX );
while ( $loopXXX->have_posts() ) : $loopXXX->the_post();
```

Comment: I dont understand how do you search in custom post types. You just loop through all custom post type. Anyway, I dont think posting a form itself would help. Because it doesnt work even though I write a keyword directly in a code as I posted before `$wp_query = Wp_Query(['post_type' => 'property', 's' => 'test']);` and work with 'post' post type. Generally what i need is that i want to get all 'property' custom post types, that contain a keyword 'test' in the title or content.

Comment: I think I just figured out what your problem is. So you want people to use the search, like they look for "apple" and want only to display the answers that contain "apple" and "test". Right?

- If this is **not** the case, then I have no idea why you even add the `'s' => 'test'` to your query.

Comment: When it will start to work with 'test' i will remove it and start using form and insert something like this $_GET['keywords'] instead of 'test'. I added it just for testing.

Comment: Yeah, try to not use it anyway, not even for testing. instead use `example.com/?s=test` Also, what file are you writing this in? Are you writing it in the search.php or have you made a custom php file for that? If so, you would need to split the result redirection, too.

Comment: I am using it in custom file. I have some select boxes in my search form for region, price, sorting which is custom fields. And with them my search is working fine with all post types. Everything works fine except for that 's'. But if i type in something in the keywords field it doesnt work. i tried to remove all other paramerters and leave only 's' and 'post type' in wp_query. then i tried to type keyword directly in the code. but it doesnt helped. but if i switch post type from 'property' to 'post' it works fine even in my search form. but i dont need posts, i need properties.

Comment: I am currently doing something similar (properties, too) but with some more custom fields than actual title/content search, maybe some of my code can help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303299/custom-search-wrong-output-question

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this,

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'tribe_events', 
      'post_per_page' =>  get_option('posts_per_page'), 
       's' => get_search_query()
   );

$query = new WP_Query($args); // Use new keyword and you need to use WP_Query not Wp_Query

while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();

     the_title();

endwhile;wp_reset_postdata();
```

I used this in `search.php` file. Worked without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the problem and you are right I had the same issue with s parameter + post_type filter.

I suppose that Wordpress do this for any reason.

You can fix this adding this in your template or in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'tgm_io_cpt_search' );
/**
 * This function modifies the main WordPress query to include an array of
 * post types instead of the default 'post' post type.
 *
 * @param object $query  The original query.
 * @return object $query The amended query.
 */
function tgm_io_cpt_search( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'property' ) );
    }

    return $query;

}

$the_query = new WP_Query( array('s' => 'test') );
```

Reference code:
https://thomasgriffin.io/how-to-include-custom-post-types-in-wordpress-search-results/

Comment: Welcome to the WP Stackexchange. While this answer is pretty correct, it is only working if you are not working with custom meta in your custom search, if the user is able to set their own filters. While giving an answer, try to maintain a scalable solution for further development.

Comment: you are the lifesaver, thanks. It works with other custom fields too

Comment: ;) happy to help!

Comment: @marvinpoo I tried to use meta_key in the query and it's working as usual. Regards!

Comment: I am leaving work right now, but I will try it when I am back at work tomorrow. But I've tried this with some very specific customization and with *conditional* searching based on post type and meta key value.

I will try it out nontheless and will report back to you ;)

Comment: if you got nervs, feel free to check this out and earn some bounty ;) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303299/custom-search-wrong-output-question